# In Physijs, how do I detect that an object is still?

Tags: 2d, physics

I have a cylinder that simulates a flipping coin. I am using [Physijs](http://chandlerprall.github.io/Physijs/). The coin might bounce off the surface multiple times before stopping. How can I know when the coin has completely stopped moving?

Comment: Use mesh.position to find it's position - check if it changes, if not - it's still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each [update event](https://github.com/chandlerprall/Physijs/wiki/Callbacks-&-Events#scene-update), simply check that the coin's linear and angular velocities are very small.

```
var epsilon = 0.0001; // or any small enough value for your purposes
if ( coin.getLinearVelocity().lengthSq() < epsilon &&
     coin.getAngularVelocity().lengthSq() < epsilon ) {
  // stopped moving
} else {
  // still moving
}
```

This approximation is often necessary because the velocities may not *quite* reach absolute `0`, due to simulation instability or [floating-point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) errors, or it may take a long time to get there.

I used `.lengthSq()` rather than `.length()` to avoid a costly square root operation. When comparing to a small value, the difference in meaning is unimportant.

Comment: Just now got to test it, works well!